# ArrayUtils has a bug? it does actually delete but

Tags: java, arrays

In case You want to test it your self:
[link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/091750563384024e0ffa
[link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f05cdd1d1685d103326

Everything worked fine in deleteItem function it deleted what i wanted, but when i tried to see the array again it shows the original array again even though I already return a new array

```
public static ItemTracker[] deleteItem(ItemTracker[] listItems) {
    for(int i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        if (listItems[i] == null) {
            break;
        } else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Everything")){
                listItems = ArrayUtils.remove(listItems, i); // ArrayUtils is actually deleting it but... see output in other function
                System.out.println("Content of Array : " + Arrays.toString(listItems)); // It deleted the index that i want and return a new array  
                // return listItems;   I tried to return here as well but same result
            } 
        }   
    }
    return listItems; // which is here
}
```

Original array: [naufal,joker,batman,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]

Output after delete items, I'm deleting joker as in index 1:

[naufal,batman,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]

It worked but..

After i run displayArray method:

```
public static void displayArray(ItemTracker[] listItems) 
     System.out.println("Content of Array : "
             + Arrays.toString(listItems));
}
```

I get:

[naufal,joker,batman,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]

same array;

I posted multiple of same questions, and tried all the solutions from people here but it doesn't work. What is the real problem over here?, seems like i couldn't of anything else.
For the sake of this problem this only applies to array not List or ArrayList

Comment: Bug on JAVA ? You serious please understand your logic first

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem (ideally with no need for user input). It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, or what output you're expecting.

Comment: show the code where you call `deleteItem` and `displayArray` please

Comment: This Question feels like you want to give light to Sun

Comment: @JonSkeet Basically what Im trying to do is passing the updated version of array in **deleteItems** to **displayArray** to show the updated version

Comment: Assuming you are using ArrayUtils from commons.lang, then a new array is created in remove(). But to see what is wrong afterwards you should post the whole code.

Comment: @guido its in the switch statement in main function

Comment: @jopa this is the whole code that i already simplified

Comment: Again, please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. We should be able to copy, paste, compile, run and see the problem. Read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet Here is the code snippets [link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/091750563384024e0ffa
[link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f05cdd1d1685d103326

Comment: No, please put the short but complete program *into your question*. And looking at the gist, that's *way* longer than you should need in order to demonstrate the problem. The point of the program should *just* be to demonstrate the problem. Hard-coded data, no user input... it should only need to be about 30 lines, if that...

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean if you want to see the whole program and by the way in the question itself I already shorten it and that is the shortest and working program i could do.

Comment: I simply don't believe that's the shortest program you can do. Why can't you hard-code some input, call `ArrayUtils.remove`, then show some incorrect result? Why do you need `printChoices`? Why do you need user input? If you're not willing to put the effort into paring down your sample code to a minimal example, it's not clear why you'd expect other people to put the effort into helping you. The code in your question isn't complete - nor is it as short as it could be.

Comment: @Naveen Check again the question

Comment: @jopa check again the question

Comment: @guido check again the question

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for your advice but i have found the solution.

Comment: I hope you will learn from this experience though. Bear in mind that if you continue to ask poor questions, you will be automatically banned from asking further ones.

Comment: @JonSkeet noted, I will read your blog to ask a good question, thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code at:

```
case 3:
   deleteItem(listItems);
   break;
```

you forgot to assign the returned array to listitems:

```
case 3:
   listItems=deleteItem(listItems);
   break;
```

Comment: You just safe my life my friend I owe you one!! btw why do I need to assign listItems=deleteItem(listItems)? and again thank you

Comment: ArrayUtils.remove() does not touch the original array but creates a copy without the removed item. So when you proceed working with the original, nothing has changed.